# Launch a program at login without permissions (fedora 20)

Tags: c++, qt, authentication, fedora20

I'm currently developing an application with QT 4.8 with a "Launch on login" option. My main problem currently is that I can't seem to find a proper way to make the program launch itself after login on Linux (Fedora 20 in my case).

My program should be able to run in the background without stopping fedora to launch.

I would also like to avoid having to ask for any sort of admin privilege since my application doesn't require any (except maybe for this option).

Comment: Is the program supposed to run on login for every user or just for the user that installs it? For the former, you certainly need `sudo` power, at least during installation.

Comment: Tbh, I do not quite see the need to do this through your program in the first place. If a user wants to autostart your program, he can just do that himself the way he wants / sees fit.

Comment: Is this under any particular desktop environment (GNOME or KDE, say)?

Comment: @Baum mit Augen for just the user that installs it. But since he has the option its not really from the installation.
Also, It's just to make the application more user friendly. I know that if you use a linux system you should have some knowledge about it... But let's say they don't.

Comment: @Mattdm no it's not under any particular desktop environment. Right now I'm trying fedora20 in particular.

Comment: The problem is: application autostart is something that's generally covered by desktop environments.

Comment: Exactly what @mattdm says. If you want to do that cleanly, you probably would have to detect the current desktop environment and handle it accordingly. Does not really sound like it is worth the effort considering someone who wants to autostart your app can just google how to. Maybe put a link like [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting) in your documentation  if you think your users are too lazy for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out about "home/.config/autostart/.desktop".

I'll have to create autostart if it's not created but from there I can chose to make or delete the file depending on what my user decided to do.

The .desktop file have to follow a particular syntax (which is not a problem for me)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=</path/to/binary or command to execute>
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=<Name_to_be_displayed>
Comment=<optional comment>
```

In my case, I can just remove the "comment" line since just the name of the application should be enough for the user to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Either keep your executable in side /etc/rc.d/rs or inside /etc/init.d folder, so that it can automatically start once device is up.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: My application currently requires to stay in another folder with other applications. I can't move everything to that folder.

Comment: This is generally terrible advice from beginning to end. It won't do anything helpful on Fedora, and certainly won't start a program after login. And even on Linux distros where something similar should work, those directories are not intended for dropping executables just right in.

Answer (score -1):

Each user has a `.bashrc` file located in their home directory, you could append a command to run your application to the end of that.

That will run when only that user logs in (I think either with graphical or terminal session)

To run for all users, look at creating a systemd service if you dare, or append a line to the end of /etc/rc.local. You'll need to be root for that though.

**EDIT:** Don't forget to put an ampersand at the end of the command to run in background.

Comment: If I add a command there, fedora waits until I leave my application, which isn't desired since I want it to run in background. I'll adjust my question.

Comment: You need to put an ampersand at the end of the command , for example:

/usr/bin/myapp &

This will run it in the background. This is true for running any command from any script (or the console), not specific to startup scripts. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Now my problem is that each time that I start a terminal my app starts with it... (in .bashrc)